# How to execute a Python3 object macro within Rivescript ".rive" script?

Tags: python-3.x, aiml, rivescript

I have the following code within the .rive file for RiveScript Interpreter, the code basically will say hello world when the user type the command "give me result":

```
> object base64 python
    import base64 as b64
    return b64.b64encode(" ".join(args))
< object
+ encode * in base64
- OK: <call>base64 <star></call>
```

Now when running that with the interpreter with the command `python3 rivescript eg/brain`, I get the right expected results. But when I try to run it with the following code:

```
from rivescript import RiveScript

bot = RiveScript()
bot.load_directory("./eg/brain")
bot.sort_replies()

while True:
    msg = raw_input('You> ')
    if msg == '/quit':
        quit()

    reply = bot.reply("localuser", msg)
    print 'Bot>', reply
```

As it mentions [here](http://pythonhosted.org/python-rivescript/rivescript.python-module.html) that Python support by default is on.

Edit: I forgott to mention the error I'm getting which is the following:

```
[ERR: Object Not Found]
```

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: What exactly is your problem..?

Comment: Your spacing (indenting) of the python object itself inside the .rive file might be wrong.
I had to use 3 spaces but Tab was using 4 so my object didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: Just reply to the bot with the trigger to that object macro.

For example: To call the object macro described include the following trigger and reply in your .rive file:

```
> object hello_world python
   print("give me result")
< object 

+ hello world
- <call>hello_world</call>
```

Comment: I tried that but not working for me, it keeps throwing this error:
[ERR: Object Not Found]